# NDB urlsafe keys and REST api requests

Tags: rest, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

I was wondering what others are doing to expose REST api endpoints with the datastore (using app engine standard). I want to use urlsafe keys but 1 - I'd rather not pass this data directly as it poses a security risk since app-engine to app-engine calls are exposed over a public ip, and 2 - the keys that are generated are very long and would not be great when multiple need to be passed as a query parameter to form a get request (and would probably exceed browser character limits).

I was thinking maybe using compression of some sort to compress the urlsafe keys which would solve both 1 and 2, but want to see if there is a better way to create REST endpoints. Or if some type of compression method is already baked into ndb?

Comment: API keys are generally not considered secure. For details, you may check the [Why and When to Use API Keys](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/when-why-api-key#security_of_api_keys) documentation page.

Comment: @George ndb urlsafe keys are unrelated to API keys and are just a mechanism for retrieval of an object in a datastore.

Answer (score 1):

Google uses HTTPS internally so I'm not sure you need to worry about it.

Also, you should probably design your app so that keys are not secret info and such that it is safe to expose them.

I use key IDs for my REST calls, which I believe are 12 digit numbers.  That works as long as you know the entity type.  If you need to specify the entity type, you could add another parameter to your API call.

Comment: The keys do not necessarily need to be secret as there is enough authentication in place to access the datastore anyways; I just don't like the idea of them being publicly exposed. I have been using IDs, but I run into the issue with entities having different ancestors and that the IDs that are generated will not be unique in this case, whereas the keys are unique.

Comment: Right, I don't use ancestors so I didn't think of that.  You'd have to combine ids of the entire lineage, which would be cumbersome.  I suppose generating a UUID is as easy as anything else.

Comment: True. The advantage of keys being however that you have a direct accessor method without the use of a query, and I believe using keys in this way would be a less costly read operation.

Comment: @yoonjesung, this is one reason I don't use ancestors.  Makes other things too complicated and I can get what I need done with the occasional cross-group transaction.

Comment: I see. Thanks for that insight. I primarily use ancestors to guarantee consistency of the objects I'm storing.